# Number of lines tangent to multiple points of a non-singular projective plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Let $C:F(x,y,z)=0$ be a projective plane curve, where $F$ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $d$. I want to show that there exists $p\in \mathcal{P}_2$ such that all lines through $p$ are tangent to $C$ at one point, at the most. I know, for example, that a general quartic plane curve has 28 bitangent lines. I'd like to generalize this to a curve of degree $d$, although I don't need to know the exact number, just that it is finite. Does anyone have any idea of how to approach this proof?

Comment: Have you thought about the dual curve? Bitangent lines of $C$ correspond to double points of the dual $C^*$.

Comment: Plane curves of degree $d$ have $d^4/2-d^3-9d^2/2+9d=(d - 3) (d - 2) d (d + 3)/2$ bitangents

Comment: You might want to look at the Gauss map to the dual plane and discuss the double points